# Is this poison ivy?

Tags: poison-ivy

I am not sure because the two opposite leaves are not on super short stems, but can I be absolutely sure that it is not?  Note: I got poison ivy blisters while working in my yard, but nobody was able to find poison ivy plants.

Pictures taken in March in Boston area.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an epimedium (perhaps Epimedium rubrum), not poison ivy.

PI typically has bat-wing style leaves, although it can be very [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxicodendron_radicans#/media/File:Toxicodendron_radicans,_leaves.jpg). All leaflets tend to be the same size, or close to it, unlike what you've pictured. The color is also somewhat off for spring foliage (it should eb a brighter red).ut then again, it's variable.

Answer (score 1):

Were you digging ? I got a bad case of poison oak while planting things in fill soil containing poison oak roots, no leaves. Photo leaves don't look much like ivy either ( osmanthus seedlings ?). Ivy does not have the little needles along the margins. In E TX where ivy is very common , the look-alike that stops me occasionally is Virginia Creeper. Could you have been exposed to poison Sumac ?

Comment: I guess it must have been roots, because nobody was able to find poison ivy in the yard, and it sounds like the pictures I sent aren't poison ivy either.  I wish there was a definitive way of telling what this thing is to be 100% sure.  Is there a way to recognize poison ivy roots?